# $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Q: If we consider $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, then how can we show they are isomorphic?

I know that if two vector spaces have bases with the same cardinality, then they are isomorphic.  Also, Zorn's lemma tells us that every vector space has a basis.

In this case, answering my question amounts to showing that any bases of  $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ have the same cardinality. In other words, I need to show dim$ \mathbb{R} =$ dim $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, that is, they have bases with the same cardinality.  Can anyone help?

Thank you!!

Comment: I am pretty sure that this question has been asked on this site before.  Can anyone find the previous question?

Comment: $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{C})=2\text{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $k$ is a field and $V$ is an infinite dimensional $k$-vector space, then $V\cong V\oplus V$. Using this, what you want to show follows from the fact that  as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces, $\mathbb C\cong \mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R$.

Can you see how to prove those two claims?

---

**Later.** Ok, apparently not. Let's do it.

**(1)** If $B$ is a basis for $V$, then the set $$B'=\{(b,0):b\in B\}\cup \{(0,b):b\in B\}$$ is a basis for $V\oplus V$. There is an obvious bijection $B'\cong \{1,2\}\times B$.

Now, if $X$ is an infinite set, then $X$ and $\{1,2\}\times X$ are in bijection. It follows from this that there is a bijection between the basis $B$ of $V$ and the basis $B'$ of $V\oplus V$. As you know, this implies that there is a linear isomorphism between $V$ and $V\oplus V$. This proves my first claim above.

**(2)** Consider the map $$\phi:a+bi\in\mathbb C\mapsto (a,b)\in\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R.$$ It is very easy to show that it is an isomorphism of $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces, so that $\mathbb C\cong\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R$, as my second claim states.

**(3)** Finally, let's prove your claim that if $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are isomorphic $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces: since $\mathbb R$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space of infinite dimensions, my first claim tells us that $\mathbb R\cong\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces. On the other hand, my second claim tells us that $\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R\cong\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces. Transitivity, then, allows us to conclude that $\mathbb R\cong\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.  However, I didn't get the idea.

Comment: If you prove the first statement, then you can show that $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then you can apply the second claim.

Comment: @yaa09d: can you be more explicit about what you do not get? I wrote two claims: with which of the two you have problems?

Comment: I think I didn't understand why the first claim holds.  
The second claim is what I was trying to show.

Comment: @yaa09d: no, my second claim is *not* what you were trying to show: you were trying to show that $\mathbb R\cong\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your eplaination is very clear.

Answer (score 9):

Two ways: one using only the fact that $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{C}|=\mathfrak{c}$; the other using the fact that we can identify the additive structure of $\mathbb{C}$ with the plane.

1. If $\mathbf{F}$ is a field and $\mathbf{V}$ is a vector space over $\mathbf{V}$, what is the cardinality of $\mathbf{V}$? If $\beta$ is a basis for $\mathbf{V}$, then every vector of $\mathbf{V}$ can be written uniquely as an $\mathbf{F}$-linear combination of vectors in $\beta$. Therefore, there is a bijection between the elements of $\mathbf{V}$ and the set
   $$\bigl\{ f\colon\beta\to \mathbf{F}\bigm| f(\mathbf{b})=\mathbf{0}\text{ for almost all }\mathbf{b}\in\beta\bigr\}.$$
   That is, the set of functions of finite support from $\beta$ to $\mathbf{F}$, $\mathbf{F}^{(\beta)}$. If $\mathbf{F}$ is infinite, then this cardinality is equal to $|\mathbf{F}||\beta|=\max\{|\mathbf{F}|,|\beta|\}$. Here, $\mathbf{F}=\mathbb{Q}$. So if $\beta$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, we need $|\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_0|\beta|$. What is $|\beta|$? For $\mathbb{C}$, we need $|\mathbb{C}| = \aleph_0|\gamma|$, where $\gamma$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. What is $|\gamma|$?
2. Since the additive structure of $\mathbb{C}$ is just the same as the additive structure of $\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$, then they are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces. So if $\{\mathbf{v}_{b}\}_{b\in\beta}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then 
   $$\bigl\{\mathbf{v}_{b}\bigr\}_{b\in\beta}\cup \bigl\{i\mathbf{v}_{b}\bigr\}_{b\in\beta}$$
   is a basis for $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (prove it). So $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{C}) = 2\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R})$. If the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ were finite, this would show they are *not* isomorphic. But is the dimension finite or infinite? And what does that tell you about the dimensions?

Comment: I think I understood your proof.  Thank you very much.

Comment: What you mentioned in 1 will imply that $|\beta|=|\mathbb{R}|$ and $|\gamma|=|\mathbb{C}|$. I am ok with that, but basically why did you say that $|\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_0|\beta|$?

Comment: @yaa09d: As I say earlier, if $\mathbf{V}$ is a vector space with basis $\beta$ over the infinite field $\mathbf{F}$, then $|\mathbf{V}|=|\mathbf{F}||\beta|$. Here, $\mathbf{F}=\mathbb{Q}$, so simply substituting into that equation, we have:$$|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{Q}||\beta|=\aleph_0|\beta|.$$

Comment: I see.  I think I got it.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you.

Comment: One last question: how did you imply that $|\mathbf{V}|=|\mathbf{F}||\beta|$ in part 1?

Comment: @yaa09d: The functions from $\beta$ to $\mathbf{F}$ that have finite support have that cardinality when $\mathbf{F}$ is infinite. For finite $\beta$, this is immediate (cardinality of $\mathbf{V}$ is just the cardinality of $\mathbf{F}$); for infinite $\beta$, you can decompose the functions by the cardinality of the support, and there are $|\beta|$ finite subsets of $\beta$; so you get a sum of $|\beta|$ terms, each of cardinality $|\mathbf{F}|$.

Comment: @Arturo: I appreciate your help. Thank you.