# Yes/No :$\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Yes/No :$\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$

## My attempt : yes

i think $\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R} \cong2 \mathbb{R}$ both have same dimension that is  dim$( \mathbb{R} )= 1$

Is its  true ?

Comment: You say $\dim(\mathbb{R})=1$. Dimension over what?

Comment: @ancientmathematician over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: then as @Fred says you are wrong in your reasoning,  though you have chosen the right answer

Comment: @jasmine If the dimension of $\Bbb R$ as a vector field over $\Bbb Q$ is $1$, then all elements are in the $\Bbb Q$-span of a single non-zero real number, say $1\in \Bbb R$. Can you express $\sqrt 2$ as a linear combination of $1$ with rational coefficients? (It seems strange to write "linear combination" with only one vector, but still.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26781

Comment: okss thanks u @Arthur sir .. i got its now

Comment: @punctureddusk thanks u

Comment: thanks u @ Fred

Comment: As clarified over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350522/415941), the problem seems to lie at $\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R\cong 2\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \mathbb  R$ as a vector space over $ \mathbb Q$ is not finite-dimensional !